# Python PATH doesn't recognize directory that is appended to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system

Recently I decided to install base Python because Anaconda was giving me a bunch of problems. I then proceeded to uninstall Anaconda (wrong order to do things, I know now). Then, everytime I installed a new library on base Python it gave me the following warning:

```
WARNING: The scripts xxx.exe, yyy.exe and zzz.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

After which, I did some research, and ran the following script:

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts'
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'+path
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```

To which the print returned:

```
C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;D:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\program files (x86)\common files\intel\shared libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;c:\program files (x86)\razer chroma sdk\bin;d:\program files\razer chroma sdk\bin;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\users\teka\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsapps;C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\GitHub CLI\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;:C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

As you can see, at the very end of the file, the path is appended, but I still get the warning everytime I install a new library. Thanks for your time!

EDIT: I printed the PATH again and the directory is not there? Maybe the PATH is set to read-only. Where can I find it to check?

EDIT 2: [My PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv6OD.png) Found the PATH, and the directories are there, but still get the warning.

Comment: I believe you need to add your executable python file in Path environment variables. I have it as: "C:\Python\python.exe". Also possibly try: "C:\Users\Teka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python" or w.e it's called in your device

Comment: I get this is obvious but have you tried restarting your system, you do know that to modify your path you have to reboot?